# input field not taking full width : ionic

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I have an input field which is in a row with one column. It's taking only half width as shown in image. Could you please help me to identify what am I missing here to make the input field taking the full width by default.

*My Code Snippet*

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div>Mobile Number</div>
        <div>
        <label class="float-right">
         <img class="edit-icon" src="./img/edit_blue.png">
        </label>
        <span> <input type="number"> </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*Output*
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can add this code to your css:

```
input[type="number"] {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
```

Or try using default ionic input

```
<label class="item item-input">
  <input type="text" placeholder="First Name">
</label>
```

Comment: The input type is taking 100% width every other place wherever I have used in the code. Though this custom css will  make my input field take 100% width, but I want to avoid the customization as it's working in other place!  Possibly am I missing any ionic tag?

Comment: Maybe, this is by default from ionic input component <label class="item item-input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name">
  </label>